# Scrolling need to work on only ion-content

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing Cordova application using ionic framework and i facing below issue.

I have  in  and  on page.

I want to just set scroll top of  on button click. i had already done that but  is also setting to top on button click.

I want to scroll only  to top and  should maintain it scroll position.

How can i do that?

Here is my structure of my page.

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-subheader" >
         <ion-scroll direction="x"  scrollbar-x="false">
             <button>1</button>
             <button>2</button>
         </ion-scroll>
   <ion-header-bar>
   <ion-content>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

has buttons arranged horizontally. When i click any of them then  and  scroll to starting position.

I want only scroll to top on any button click.